# get the times of users login and logout in local network

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i want to save details of time of logining on and logining off any users in my local network.
now this events are in eventlog of server system and i should run my app only on this pc to get this information and it's not good.
now my question is can i give access permission to security of eventlog to any users that they save this information to database??
or how can admin access to this information from client pc??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the lastLogon y lasLogoff properties of the Active Directory (I'm not sure if this properties work if you are not in a domain).
You can use [Beaver Tail](http://adsi.mvps.org/adsi/CSharp/beavertail.html) to see how is this done.