# How to get the logout time of the user from computer

Tags: c#

I wanted to get the User name, last log in and log out time from Computer Management.

Trying with below code, getting `null` for log out time:

```
foreach (DirectoryEntry de in dirs.Children)
{
    if (de.SchemaClassName == "User")
    {   wr.WriteLine();
        wr.Write(de.Path);
        wr.Write(",");
        if (de.Properties["lastlogin"].Value != null)
        {
            wr.Write(de.Properties["lastlogin"].Value.ToString());
            wr.Write(",");
        }
        else
            wr.Write(",");
        if (de.Properties["lastLogoff"].Value != null)
        {
            wr.Write(de.Properties["lastLogoff"].Value.ToString());
            wr.Write(",");
        }
        else
            wr.Write(",");
    }
```

Comment: @abhitalks, that last closing brace wasn't in the original code.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145717/get-the-times-of-users-login-and-logout-in-local-network

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Oh yes, I got it mixed up, I thought it was lost as my edit was abandoned while you were at it. Sorry for the confusion. I see you have reset it. Thanks.